# To get index of Tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am aware of onTabChanged method to get the current tab id. Could you please guide me to get the index of the tab.

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    currentTab =  tabId;  
    updatetab(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
mytabs.getCurrentTab();
```

Comment: Beat me to it (but only just). :)

Comment: When people decide to answer, we all do it at the same time don't we XD

Comment: It is not working

  @Override
 public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     currentTab =  tabId;  

      Log.i("NewTicket", "Im currently in tab with index::" + th.getCurrentTab());
  updatetab(); 
 } 
12-24 23:37:23.949: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 23:37:23.949: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 23:37:23.949: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):  at com.example.restaurent.NewTicket.onItemClick(NewTicket.java:175)
12-24 23:37:23.949: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):at

Comment: Log.i("NewTicket", "Im currently in tab with index::" + th.getCurrentTab());

Comment: TabHost th; is the declaration.. I have declared it twice.. once in the oncreate and one before oncreate ..  i have corrected it. Now it is working.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `getCurrentTab()` on your `TabHost` - I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tab instead of TabHost use this construction to return the currently selected tab:

```
Tab currentTab = actionBar.getSelectedTab();
```

From there you can read it or modify it.  For example if want to change the color of the active tab's text you could do this:

```
currentTab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_active_tab_layout);
TextView currentTabView = (TextView) currentTab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.ActiveTab);
currentTabView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple) );
```

Obviously, you'll also need a simple layout file as well such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ActiveTab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="tab name" 
    android:textColor="@color/Gray"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textScaleX="1.3"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```